# How to override tooltip that is set in asp.net master page in content page programatically

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a  table with  columns in below mentioned structure

```
Sl.no  name    hierarchy
1      Animal  null
2      cat     animal
3      tiger   animal/cat
```

The requirement is when we show name in a list box or dropdownlist ,when we hover over the name say tiger its hirerchy ie animal/cat should be displayed as a tooltip which is getting displayed using title attribute.

the problem is the master page has a default js code on document ready to display tooltip based on text whenever hovered over ie on hovering over "tiger" we get tooltip as "tiger".

so when this master page is linked to the content page that has the dropdown ,only the default tooltip gets displayed and teh hierarchy is not getting displayed.

Could you please provide a solution on how to override the master page code in content page?